# Rewrite directory URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory structure like this:

```
http://example.com/directory/folder/files/
```

I want to rewrite the URL with htaccess so that when a user visits:

```
http://example.com/path/
```

They are served the files from `http://example.com/directory/folder/files/`.

Essentially, I want to replace `directory/folder/files/` with `path/`

How can I do this?

I've been trying this at the moment, but it doesnt work, it just adds `path` infront of the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule ^directory/folder/files/$ path/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule you would need is reverse of what you've attempted. Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule ^path/(.*)$ /directory/folder/files/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a slash at the beginning or

```
RewriteBase /
```